# Banshee intergration with Xubuntu

Tags: banshee, xubuntu

I am using Banshee on Xubuntu 11.10 and I face few problems:

- Banshee does not appear on the panel when iconified *(reported as bug [668670](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=668670))*;
- Banshee bindings with my [play/pause][stop][pre][next] buttons is not consistent. (Sometimes it controls Banshee and some other times it doesn't) *(reported as bug [668671](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=668671))*.

Are these bugs or merely configuration issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Banshee does not appear on the panel when iconified;

This sounds like a bug, and you may wish to [report it to the Banshee team](http://banshee.fm/contribute/file-bugs/).

> Banshee bindings with my [play/pause][stop][pre][next] buttons is not consistent. (Sometimes it controls Banshee and some other times it doesn't).

If other media players are open, they may steal the functionality of your media keys. For example, media keys have no effect in Banshee if Totem (Movie Player) is open.

Comment: I cannot find among processes any other media player other than Banshee.

Comment: I was just going to say, in that case the second issue also sounds like a bug, but I see you already reported it. :)